# How to select and deselect graphs in QCustomPlot

Tags: qcustomplot

I have 2 QCPGraph and 2 QCPItemText, and, on click on one of them, I want to select them all if they are deselected and deselect if the are selected or on click on empty space

I tried to implement this through QCP selection mechanism with QCP::iSelectPlottables, but this way, graphs can't be clicked second time. I think that it can be done with QCP signal plottableClick, but I think it will make program very complicated